# Break the nested while loops in unix scripting

Tags: unix

Have two files:
file1 is having the key words - INFO ERROR
file2 is having the list of log files path - path1 path2
I need to exit out of the script if any of the condition in any of the loops failed.

Here is the Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
RC=0
while read line 
do
  echo "grepping from the file $line
  if [ -f $line ]; then
     while read key
     do
       echo "searching $key from the file $line
       if [ condition ]; then
          RC=0;
       else
          RC=1;
          break;
       fi
     done < /apps/file1 
else
   RC=1;
   break;
fi
done < apps/file2
exit $RC
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The ansewer to your question is using `break 2`:

```
while true; do 
   sleep 1
   echo "outer loop"
   while true; do 
      echo "inner loop"
      break 2
   done
done
```

I never use this, it is terrible when you want to understand or modify the code.
Already better is using a boolean

```
found_master=
while [ -n "${found_master}" ]; do 
   sleep 1
   echo "outer loop"
   while true; do 
      echo "inner loop"
      found_master=true
      break 
   done
done
```

When you do not need the variable found_master it is an ugly additional variable.
You can use a function

```
inner_loop() {
    local i=0;
    while ((i++ < 5)); do
      ((random=$RANDOM%5))
      echo "Inner $i: ${random}"
      if [ ${random} -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "Returning 0"
         return 0
      fi
    done;
    return 1;
}

j=0
while ((j++ < 5 )); do
   echo "Out loop $j"
   inner_loop
   if [  $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "inner look broken"
      break
   fi
done
```

But your original problem can be handles without two while loops.
You can use `grep -E "INFO|ERROR" file2` or combining the keywords. When the keywords are on different lines in file1, you can use `grep -f file1 file2`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `condition` with `$(grep -c ${key} ${line}) -gt 0` like this:

```
echo "searching $key from the file $line
       if [ $(grep -c ${key} ${line}) -eq 0 ]; then
```

It will count the each key-word in your log-file. If count=0 (pattern didn't found), running `then`. If found at least 1 key, running `else`, `RC=1` and exit from loop.

And be sure, that your key-words can't be substrings of the longest words, or you will get an error.

Example:

```
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ cat file 
correctstringERROR and more useless text

ERROR thats really error string
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ grep -c ERROR file 
2
```

If you wish to avoid count 2 (because counting first string, obliviously, bad way), you should also add two keys for grep:

```
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ grep -cow ERROR file 
1
```

Now you have counted only the **words** equal to your key, not **substrings** in any useful strings.